# Install Thunderbird 60 with ppa

Tags: apt, 18.04, kubuntu, ppa, thunderbird

I want to install Thunderbird 60 on my Kubuntu 18.04. I know I can do it over ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

but it will still install thunderbird 52 because of the policy

```
$ apt-cache policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Installiert:           1:60.5.3+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Installationskandidat: 1:1000~52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
     1:1000~52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plasmazilla/releases/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    1:60.5.3+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:60.5.1+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:60.5.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~mt1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I can now force to use the 60.5.3 build, but then, every time I want to update the system, it also wants to "update" thunderbird to v52.

Snap package is not a solution, since it has no thunderbird-plasma integration, so attachments don't work (no working "open with" function).

At the moment, I just "hold" the current version by:

```
sudo apt-mark hold thunderbird
```

but with this, I will never get updates (so I could directly install it over tar.gz as well).

I also tried to fix it with [Pin Priority](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto), by creating

the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozillateam-pin-1100` and setting it to

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1100
```

but it didn't work for me. As you can see in the above policy output:

`1:1000~52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500`

The version number is somehow increased to 1000. Maybe thats the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is useful also for those who want to downgrade from T68 to a previous version. T68 basically broke all the plugins/extensions.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1559628